# Extract only the data without the header - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I extract only the data without the header?

```
clc;
clear all;
 
mt = readtable('messy.csv','TreatAsEmpty',{'.','NA'});
tableHeader = mt.Properties.VariableNames 
tableData = mt(:,:)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to convert a table in an array without headers:

```
tableData = mt{:,:}
```

other solution (output -> matrix, get only numbers):

```
tableData = table2array(mt)
```

other solution (output -> cell, get strings too):

```
tableData = table2cell(mt)
```

Comment: tableData = table2cell(mt) works the best. thanks